Python Web scraping [D:websockets.client] > GET %s HTTP/1.1 [D:websockets.client] > %s: %s doesn't show all the results
I'm trying to make web scraping with Python 3.10, and the library requests-HTML 0.10.0.
I attach the code:
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = 'https://bodysolid-europe.com/collections/all'

s = HTMLSession()
r = s.get(url)

r.html.render(sleep=1)

products = r.html.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div', first=True)

for item in products.absolute_links:
    r = s.get(item)
    print(r.html.find('header.product-header', first=True).text)

When I try to extract information from the URL by Xpath, in the console shows the next output:
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] Starting new HTTPS connection (%d): %s:%s
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
[D:asyncio] Using proactor: %s
[D:websockets.client] = connection is CONNECTING
[D:websockets.client] > GET %s HTTP/1.1
[D:websockets.client] > %s: %s
[D:websockets.client] > %s: %s
[D:websockets.client] > %s: %s
[D:websockets.client] > %s: %s
[D:websockets.client] > %s: %s
[D:websockets.client] > %s: %s
[D:websockets.client] > %s: %s
[D:websockets.client] < HTTP/1.1 %d %s

It doesn't show all the information from the items, only a little bit, like these:
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
Body-Solid Europe
Best Fitness Dumbbell Rack BFDR10
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
Best Fitness
Best Fitness Bench BFFID10
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
Best Fitness
Best Fitness Mountain Climber BFMC10
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
Body-Solid Europe
Best Fitness Multi-Station Gym BFMG30
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
Best Fitness
Best Fitness Center Drive Elliptical BFE1
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
Best Fitness
Best Fitness Olympic Bench BFOB10
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
Best Fitness
Best Fitness Functional Trainer BFFT10
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
Best Fitness
Best Fitness Leg Developer and Preacher Curl Attachment BFPL10
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
Best Fitness
Best Fitness Inversion Table BFINVER10
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
[D:urllib3.connectionpool] %s://%s:%s "%s %s %s" %s %s
Body-Solid Europe

The most of the output are only:
D:websockets.client] < %s
[D:websockets.client] < %s
[D:websockets.client] < %s
[D:websockets.client] < %s
[D:websockets.client] < %s
[D:websockets.client] < %s
[D:websockets.client] < %s
[D:websockets.client] < %s
[D:websockets.client] < %s
[D:websockets.client] < %s
[D:websockets.client] < %s
[D:websockets.client] < %s
[D:websockets.client] < %s
[D:websockets.client] < %s
[D:websockets.client] < %s
[D:websockets.client] < %s
[D:websockets.client] < %s
[D:websockets.client] < %s
[D:websockets.client] < %s
[D:websockets.client] < %s
[D:websockets.client] < %s

I don't know what the problem is. I already installed the  pyppeteer==1.0.0, because previously, I had this:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>. The specified key does not exist.</Message><Details> No such object: chromium-browser-snapshots/Win_x64/1181205/chrome-win.zip</Details></Error>

but now it's showing the "[D:websockets.client] < %s
[D:websockets.client] < %s"
I need to fix that error with the output to get the information from the URL by web scraping.

This seems like a bug in the websockets.client package.

I've faced the same problem, then i change the version of pyppeteer to 1.0.2, it stop showing that annoying things.
I also add these two lines:
PYPPETEER_CHROMIUM_REVISION = "1263111"
os.environ["PYPPETEER_CHROMIUM_REVISION"] = PYPPETEER_CHROMIUM_REVISION


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
